# Vista: Do I use all of my memory?

Tags: windows-vista, memory

I just installed 2 gb extra ram memory in my pc (going from 2 to 4 gb).
However, it seems like windows vista doesn't use it:

[image]

In windows task manager it says I've got only 3 gb of physical memory.
In the system settings it does recognize 4 gb.
Is this something that I should fix (for better performance).
If so, how could I fix this ?

**Edit**
I still don't know how to fix this. I hope this screenshot will help identify the problem:
[image]

I've no clue how installed RAM is 4 GB, and total phsycal memory is 2.94 GB. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Are you using integrated graphics? How much RAM is allotted to it?

Comment: Assuming you are using a 32-bit version of Vista, this is a duplicate of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/292563/more-than-4-gb-of-ram-on-vista-x86/292566#292566

Comment: @uSlackr I think it is clear from the picture that I'm using 64-bit.

Comment: @Karan I don't have integrated graphics. I have ati radeon 1900 XTX

Comment: Use RAMMap and see what's using the 1GB of RAM.

Comment: @Karan According to RAMMap my total is 3.079.352 KB of RAM.

Comment: Can you try removing and properly reseating all your RAM sticks?

Comment: run msconfig.exe and make sure you're not limiting the RAM.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not limiting the RAM.

Comment: @Karan I tried, I put them in different slots, but still exactly the same.

Comment: @Kasper - Can you post a dxdaig log report.  Might give us some inishgt if your video card is consuming the memory or not.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Russinovich's article is still the best explanation for all this that I've found: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

He discusses the memory ranges takes by drivers, etc that limit what's available in 4GB systems.

Comment: Doesn't seem to explain why Total Physical Memory shown in Task Manager is 1GB less than the Installed Memory shown in System Properties.